# Convert SQL query in Django model format

Tags: sql, django, join, django-models, count

I'm trying to convert an SQL query into django format but as I'm quite new to django I'm having some trouble.

My query:

```
select make_name, count(*) as count from main_app_make as make
join main_app_model as model on make.id = model.make_id
join main_app_vehicle as vehicle on model.id = vehicle.model_id
group by make.make_name
```

The result:

```
Audi    1
Mercedes-Benz   2
```

My models:

```
class Make(models.Model):
    make_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    make_logo = models.CharField(max_length=400)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.make_name


class Model(models.Model):
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    make = models.ForeignKey(Make, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_name

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(VehicleType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body_type = models.ForeignKey(Body, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
...
```

This is what I tried:

```
options = Make.objects.all().values('make_name').annotate(total=Count('make_name'))
```

Comment: The ORM query seems fine to me, What you have got when you tried?

Comment: I get ```Audi    1
Mercedes-Benz   1 ```

Comment: What happens if you try : `options = Make.objects.prefetch_related('model_set__vehicle_set').values('make_name').annotate(total=Count('make_name'))` ?

Comment: ```SELECT `main_app_make`.`make_name`, COUNT(`main_app_make`.`make_name`) AS `total` FROM `main_app_make` GROUP BY `main_app_make`.`make_name` ORDER BY NULL``` This query is generated and I still get the same result as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to include the children models in the `Count` :

```
options = Make.objects.values('make_name').annotate(total=Count('model_set__vehicle_set'))
```

Reference : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards